# Lumen 5.6 - php artisan db:seed got error 'Class DatabaseSeeder does not exist'

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to seed with `Lumen 5.6.3` and executed the command:
`php artisan db:seed`.

Then I got error, saying

```
In Container.php line 767:
Class DatabaseSeeder does not exist
```

In my `database/seeds` directory, `DatabaseSeeder.php` does exist.
I've just copied the source in Lumen's official document and the source is like below.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I've googled many times to solve this error and of course tried `composer dump-autoload`, `composer dump-autoload -o`, `composer dump-autoload --no-dev` several times and the situation has never changed.

I also checked my `composer/autoload_classmap.php` and there is `'DatabaseSeeder' => $baseDir . '/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php'` so I looks like autoload does work correctly.

I really appreciate any advices or comments.
Thank you.

Comment: Lumen doesn't come with the ability to seed DB, you're going to have to implement that yourself or switch to Laravel

Comment: I did `php artisan list` and found `db:seed` so thought Lumen has db seeding function... Thank you, I try to find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a wrong value for bootstrap/app.php.

I set like the below.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

After I modified this part like following, I could run `db:seed` command correctly.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, you have to tweak your composer.json in order for 
`php artisan db:seed`
to work

By default, Lumen has placed the database directory under autoload-dev. 

`"autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/",
            "database/"
        ]
},`

To solve this, simple put the classmap together with your database directory under autoload

`"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/"
        ]
},`

after tweaking run `composer update` command in order for the tweak to work.

Comment: Thank you. I modified composer.json and ran composer update, but the situation has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php artisan db:seed with lumen.
The command is:  php artisan make:seeder Seedername.
For example you can use php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder to create table seeder for the user.
The file will be created in the folder database\seeds.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();
    }
}
```

This will create 10 example for the user class.
Then you should cinfigure the databaseseeder file

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        // Register the user seeder
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's good to know "db:seed" command does exist. However, php artisan db:seed command still returns "DatabaseSeeder does not exist" error.

Comment: I still got this:

`Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

In FactoryBuilder.php line 269:
                                                             
  Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\User].`